# Making PHP composable and look functional

Tags: php, functional-programming

I've found myself on numerous occasions needing to with large text-files, where joining this on that, and filtering this out on arbitrary conditions.

The first couple of times, this turned into a loop in a loop in a loop mess which was indented more times than I care to either remember or admit.

More recently, I've attempted to make something that looks and behaves more ["functional"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). Below is the basic class and a simple example.

I'm primarily concerned with extensibility. I'm not sure the approach I use will lend itself to extensibility in the future. I though, for example, about trying to stream results to disc, and I'm not sure that's doable at all without a fundamental change. Similarly it would be useful to add a simple ->not() for negating a filter, which I also don't see easily doable here.

A secondary concern is performance. PHP is perhaps not the best choice for a functional style. I'm guessing the performance of all these function calls isn't fantastic. Anything obvious I can do to improve it? If "real" performance is a requirement, the obvious suggestion might just to be to not use PHP, but if there are cheap ways to stretch this further, it would be nice.

Code:

```
class Functional {
  protected $result;
  protected $extra_data;

  public function __construct($array = NULL) {
    $this->result = $array;
  }

  public function reduce($callback, $i = NULL) {
    if ($i === NULL) {
      $i = $this->result;
    }

    $result = array_reduce($i, $callback);
    $this->result = $result;
    return $this;
  }

  public function walk($callback, $i = NULL) {
    if ($i === NULL) {
      $i = $this->result;
    }

    array_walk($i, $callback);
    $this->result = $i;
    return $this;
  }

  public function filter($callback, $i = NULL) {
    if ($i === NULL) {
      $i = $this->result;
    }

    $this->result = array_filter($i, $callback);
    return $this;
  }

  public function result() {
    return $this->result;
  }

  public function gather($callback, $key) {
    $this->extra[$key] = $callback($this->result)
    return $this;
  }

  public function extra($key) {
    return $this->extra[$key];
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$f = new Functional($a);
$result = $f->walk(function(&$i) { return $i *= 2; })
  ->reduce(function($i, $j) { return $i + $j; })
  ->result();

var_dump($result);

int(20)
```

Comment: whenever a function expects a function as an argument, it'd be best to add the `callable` type-hint. All in all, I'd also say that you're taking a tool (PHP), and try to use it as something it's not (ie a functional language). You can sort of pull this off, but it's not the best thing to do, IMHO. Using JS, or Scheme, or Haskell would be my advice

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point... It wasn't available until PHP 5.4 though, right? Sadly I still need it to work in PHP 5.3 as well, despite it's EOL status. I do utilize 5.4 features in the tests (which aren't posted), but I'm avoiding that in the main code for now.

Comment: Well, if it performance is an issue and if you need to convince anyone to upgrade: moving to PHP 5.5 easily gives you a 20~30% performance boost, possibly more (after upgrading, we saw an increase of well over 25%)

Comment: As from what I have learned, in functional programming each function only depends on its own arguments and on nothing more. Can a function utilizing `$this->` be a part of functional programming?

Comment: @feeela I assume you are thinking of [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). I titled the question "look functional", because I'm aware that it won't be pure.

Comment: @feeela: That's rubbish. I'm sorry, but closures/lambda's are common in (and indeed a key feature of) functional languages, they don't always result in pure functions, though

Answer (score 2):

I propose you a more compact version with code duplication removal:

You can compact all of your call with an `apply` method, as shown in the following code:

```
<?php

class Functional
{
    protected $result;
    protected $extra_data;

    public function __construct($array = NULL)
    {
        $this->result = $array;
    }

    protected function apply($fn, $callback, $value)
    {
        $input = (is_null($value)) ? $this->result : $value;
        call_user_func($fn, $input, $callback);
        return $this;
    }

    public function reduce($callback, $i = NULL)
    {
        return $this->apply('array_reduce', $callback, $i);
    }

    public function walk($callback, $i = NULL)
    {
        return $this->apply('array_walk', $callback, $i);
    }

    public function filter($callback, $i = NULL)
    {
        return $this->apply('array_filter', $callback, $i);
    }

    public function result()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }

    public function gather($callback, $key)
    {
        $this->extra[$key] = $callback($this->result);
        return $this;
    }

    public function extra($key)
    {
        return $this->extra[$key];
    }
}
```